# Force macro to put a space between 2 tokens

Tags: c, macros

```
#define HELPER(param) Wazz ##param

HELPER(hek)
```

Doing a `gcc -E filename` shows me

```
Wazzhek
```

How do I get `Wazz hek`? How do I insert a space between the 2 tokens?

```
#define HELPER(param) Wazz ## ## ##param
```

Doesnt work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do not use token concatenation operator when you don't want to do token concatenation.

```
#define HELPER(param) Wazz param

HELPER(hek)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt think of that